# Filter array item on basis of a format

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, redux

I have an array with two elements.
When my sportsPaperRank is this format xxx-xx-xxxx and weight starts with 80,and search.sportsSwim === "hi" || search.sportsSwim === "hello", I need to ignore that value, 
but right now its ignoring both the items, but I need to display first item, because the value of weight starts with 55.
Can you tell me how to fix it?

Right now I did a regular expression check and match check,
but nothing working.
Can you tell me how to fix it?

```js
let data = [
    {
      "weight": 555666111,
      "sportsBall": "wewewe",
      "sportsSwim": "hi",
      "sportsPaperRank": "xxx-xx-0000",
      "sportsHeight": "wew",
      "sportsRing": "yuyu",
      "sportsBat": "yuyu-ioioioio",
      "playing": "erioioerio"
    },
    {
      "weight": 80035647,
      "sportsBall": "klklkl",
      "sportsSwim": "hello",
      "sportsPaperRank": "xxx-xx-0000",
      "sportsRing": "yuyu",
      "sportsBat": "yuyu-ioioioio",
      "playing": "erioioerio"
    },
{
 "weight": 80035649,
 "sportsBall": "klklkl",
 "sportsSwim": "hello",
 "sportsPaperRank": "22-2340000",
 "sportsRing": "yuyu",
 "sportsBat": "yuyu-ioioioio",
 "playing": "erioioerio"
   }
  ];

  console.log(
            'data.--->',
            data
        );
        console.log(
            'data[0]--->',
            data[0].sportsPaperRank
        );
        let patternEIN = /^\d{2}\-?\d{7}$/;
        //let patternEIN = /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/;
        // let patternEIN = (/^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$/ | /^XXX-XX-XXXX$/);

        console.log('no dashpattern check--->', ('xxxxx0000' === patternEIN));

        console.log('pattern check hard --->', ('xxx-xx-0000' === patternEIN));
        console.log('pattern check s--->', (data[0].sportsPaperRank === patternEIN));
        console.log('pattern check .toString()--->', (data[0].sportsPaperRank.toString() === patternEIN));

        let resultSports = data.filter(
            search => {
                console.log("pattern matching ", search.sportsPaperRank.match(patternEIN));
                (search.weight) &&
                    (search.weight.toString().startsWith('80')) &&
                    (search.sportsSwim === "hi" || search.sportsSwim === "hello") &&
                    (search.sportsPaperRank.match(/xxx/g))

            }

        );

        console.log(' resultSports--->', resultSports);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your result by using `regex` in `if()` condition. Here is your code snippet:

```
 var data1 = [
        {
          "weight": 555666111,
          "sportsBall": "wewewe",
          "sportsSwim": "hi",
          "sportsPaperRank": "xxx-xx-0000",
          "sportsHeight": "wew",
          "sportsRing": "yuyu",
          "sportsBat": "yuyu-ioioioio",
          "playing": "erioioerio"
        },
        {
          "weight": 80035647,
          "sportsBall": "klklkl",
          "sportsSwim": "hello",
          "sportsPaperRank": "xxx-xx-0000",
          "sportsRing": "yuyu",
          "sportsBat": "yuyu-ioioioio",
          "playing": "erioioerio"
        }
      ];

    var resultSports = data1.filter(function(search){
        if((!search.sportsPaperRank.match(/\w{4}-\w{2}-[0-9]{4}/gm)) && (!search.weight.toString().match(/^80/gm)) && ((search.sportsSwim === "hi") || (search.sportsSwim === "hello"))){
            return search;
        }
    });
    console.log(resultSports);
```

Here, you will get the single object having `weight:555666111` and `"sportsPaperRank": "xxx-xx-0000"`.

You can check my regex for `sportsPaperRank:xxxx-xx-0000` in this **[link](https://regex101.com/r/Dz8M20/1)**.

You can check my regex for `"weight": 555666111` in this **[link](https://regex101.com/r/O3tVMJ/1)**.

Comment: This looks correct. just that OP added a new condition " search.sportsSwim === "hi" || search.sportsSwim === "hello" "... You might want to include that too.

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama hey its ignoring this format too  `"sportsPaperRank": "22-2340000",` can you fix it updated my question

Comment: @jered hey i updated your codesandbox but its not working correctly, actually it should ignore only one item https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-shockley-v3f1b can you update my sandbox

Comment: No , it is working properly because in your question you mentioned that the object having sportsPaperRank is  format xxx-xx-xxxx , weight starts with 80 and search.sportsSwim === "hi" || search.sportsSwim === "hello" should be ignored . Therefore the object in `codesandbox` last contains format xxx-xxxxxx and also start with 80 therefore everytime if the  weight starts with 80 it will ignore everytime . As a result you will only get the 1 object in result . @zfzf

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama ok thanks , can you help me with the other format too, `when it starts with 80 and this format xxx-xx-0000 alone I need to ignore, and another item if it starts with 80 and this format 00-000000 I need not ignore it, can you update in my sandbox` codesandbox.io/s/gifted-shockley-v3f1b

Comment: Okk i will .. Going back to workplace in 30 mins .. I will solve Your problem .. Can you please upvote ?

Comment: `search.sportsSwim === "hi" || search.sportsSwim === "hello"` , what about this condition ? @zfzf

Comment: You can check out the code in this link https://codesandbox.io/embed/patient-wildflower-2nt2g . @zfzf

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama hey we need to include remaining conditions too like this ones `search.sportsSwim === "hi" || search.sportsSwim === "hello"`can you update in sandbox

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with three regular expressions.

### To check that a string starts with `80`:

`/^80/`

1. `^` asserts that the match is at the beginning of the string
2. `80` matches the character literal string `80` exactly

```
/^80/.test(8012381); // true
/^80/.test(8800000); // false
```

https://regex101.com/r/TvbQ3D/1

### To check that a string has the format `XXX-XX-XXXX` where `X` is a numeric digit:

`/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/`

1. `^` asserts that the match is at the beginning of the string
2. `\d{3}` matches 2 numeric digits in a row
3. `-` matches the `-` character literal
4. `\d{2}` matches 3 numeric digits in a row
5. `-` matches the `-` character literal
6. `\d{4}` matches 4 numeric digits in a row
7. `$` asserts that the match is at the end of the string

```
/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/.test("123-45-6789"); // true
/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/.test("00-000-000"); // false
/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/.test("A00-00-0000"); // false
```

Note: if you don't want to limit the `X` in this format to numeric digits, you could swap it out `\d` with `\w` which will match "word" characters (0-9, a-z, A-Z, and _): `/^\w{3}-\w{2}-\w{4}$/`

https://regex101.com/r/gGBc4z/4

### To match that a string is *exactly* `hi` *or* `hello`:

`/^hi|hello$/`

1. `^` asserts that the match is at the beginning of the string
2. `hi` matches the character literal string `hi` exactly
3. `|` is an 'or' operator that will let you list multiple valid matches
4. `hello` matches the character literal string 'hello' exactly
5. `$` asserts that the match is at the end of the string

https://regex101.com/r/jhLMzi/1

```
/^hi|hello$/.test("hi"); // true
/^hi|hello$/.test("hello"); // true
/^hi|hello$/.test("something else); // false
```

Note: the `^` and `$` help ensure that you are matching a string of the exact length and format that you're specifying.

---

Now, simply use those regular expressions to *exclude* any object with a `"weight"` field starting with 80, and a `"sportsPaperRank"` field matching `XXX-XX-XXXX`, and a `"sportsSwim"` field matching either "hi" or "hello":

```
let resultSports = data.filter(ea => !(
  /^80/.test(ea.weight) &&
  /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/.test(ea.sportsPaperRank) && 
  /^hi|hello$/.test(ea.sportsSwim)
));
```

Comment: hey can you put it in separate if conditions, its so confusing `(search.weight.toString().startsWith('80')) &&
                    (search.sportsSwim === "hi" || search.sportsSwim === "hello") &&
                    (search.sportsPaperRank.match(/xxx/g))`

Comment: @zfzf If you have additional things that you need to match your string or object on, then please update your original question. Right now you have only specified "when my sportsPaperRank is this format xxx-xx-xxxx and weight starts with 80, I need to ignore that value." so that is what my answer addresses. If it is helpful for you, please upvote and accept it, or clarify your question. :)

Comment: @jered your solution is incorrect. weight is a different field. What you are checking is whether sportsPaperRank starts with 80. OP has specified it clearly that sportsPaperRank is in format xxx-xx-xxxx and weight starts with 80.

Comment: @jered hey its ignoring this format too  `"sportsPaperRank": "22-2340000",` can you fix it updated my question too

Comment: @zfzf I'm not sure what you mean by "its ignoring this format too". The regex I gave will not match that pattern. Perhaps you have a transcription error - check your code carefully. Regardless, I have given very detailed explanations of the regular expressions and what they do. At this point I think it is within your power to use problem solving and research to figure out the rest. We are not here to write all your code for you, and I have already given very specific solutions to point you in the right direction. If my answer has been helpful to you, please upvote and accept it. :)

Comment: @jered hey i updated your codesandbox but its not ignoring one item also in that array, actually it should ignore only one item https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-shockley-v3f1b can you update my sandbox